# How to change the table theme in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, themes

Here is my sample code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(shinythemes)
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


###
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("123"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol",
        "123:",
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 400,
        selected = 1
      ),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
      bsTooltip(id = "plot1", title = "Please be patient as this calculation process takes some time.", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      actionButton(inputId = "dataTable", label = "dataTable",width=100,class = "btn btn-primary"), 
),
      tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link",target = "_top"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      #uiOutput("all")
      tags$style(HTML("
                    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    }
### ADD THIS HERE ###
                    .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button{box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;min-width:1.5em;padding:0.5em 1em;margin-left:2px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none !important;cursor:pointer;*cursor:hand;color:#ffffff !important;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:2px}

###To change text and background color of the `Select` box ###
                    .dataTables_length select {
                           color: #0E334A;
                           background-color: #0E334A
                           }

###To change text and background color of the `Search` box ###
                    .dataTables_filter input {
                            color: #0E334A;
                            background-color: #0E334A
                           }

                    thead {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    }

                     tbody {
                    color: #000000;
                    }

                   "
      )),
      dataTableOutput('dataTable')
      
    )
  )
  


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## put sd into mean_data
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })
  
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
    ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                  ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p1()
  })
  output$dataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({mean_data})
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I use the superhero shiny theme. But it caused my table output doesn't appear so suitable to the shiny theme.

The output result like this:

[image]

**Just adjust the table theme. Don't focus on other details.**

Please give me some adivce.Vary thankful.

I also add the table theme in my code.But I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Can somebody give me some advice

Comment: @YBS Plz,sir.If you are free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by myself.

**Though the modified code is till confused me. But I know how to change the color in which place that I wanna change.**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(shinythemes)
mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


###
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("123"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "selectGeneSymbol",
        "123:",
        choices = colnames(mean_data)[-1],
        multiple =F,
        width = 400,
        selected = 1
      ),
      
      actionButton(inputId = "plot1", label = "FPKM"),
      bsTooltip(id = "plot1", title = "Please be patient as this calculation process takes some time.", placement = "right", trigger = "hover"),
      actionButton(inputId = "dataTable", label = "dataTable",width=100,class = "btn btn-primary"), 
    ),
    tags$h6(tags$a(href="https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/", "link",target = "_top"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot"),
    #uiOutput("all")
    tags$style(HTML("
                        .dataTables_filter input {
                            color: #000000;
                            background-color: #ffffff
                           }

                    thead {
                    color: #ff7500;
                    }
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    color: #ff7500;
}
 
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    color: #ff7500 !important;
}
 
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
    color: #ff7500 !important;"
    )),
    dataTableOutput('dataTable')
    
  )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## put sd into mean_data
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1, { 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })
  
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1, {
    ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]], fill=Name,
                                  ymin = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] - sd, ymax = .data[[input$selectGeneSymbol]] + sd )) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      # geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] - sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol], ymax = plotdata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol] + sddata()[,input$selectGeneSymbol]), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      geom_errorbar(width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$selectGeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "123_value")
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p1()
  })
  output$dataTable <- DT::renderDataTable({mean_data})
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Just like above:

The vital part of my code here:

```
tags$style(HTML("
                        .dataTables_filter input {
                            color: #000000;
                            background-color: #ffffff
                           }

                    thead {
                    color: #ff7500;
                    }
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
    color: #ff7500;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    color: #ff7500 !important;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current:hover {
    color: #ff7500 !important;"
    )),
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: You can give me other methods to my question. Appreciate it.